# Is it okay to "Sample by rows" when updating statistics

Tags: sql-server

On MS SQL Server, during the night we like to update the statistics, but this process is taking a long time and runs well into the morning.

Is it okay sample by rows where the number of rows is +100,000?  or will this give the wrong statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Are you current using a FULLSCAN or PERCENT?  How are you queries performing under your current scheme?  It isn't necessarily easy but from my experience tying the two, UPDATE STATISTICS to query performance, provides a more arguable position for changing.  Presumably the running well into the morning is causing issues.  Whether or not a row count is "Okay" is a bit like the car ad ("your mileage may vary").

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be answered by sheer volume of rows. You need to consider selectivity and density for a start.

Take a look at this article for more information:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/